# Bootstrap nested rows not working on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The following code produce wider nested row on the right end side when I run on ripple Iphone5 and Android Galaxy simulator. The total column width on the nested row are equal to 12 but the spread differ on the first ant the last column. How to solve this if I want to keep the same distribution.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!--Loadsheet calcs  section-->
        <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color: steelblue">
            <!--Loadsheet Header-->
            <div class="row" style="background-color:greenyellow;">
                <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:navajowhite">4</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color:orange">3</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color:yellow">3 </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color:aqua">2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Loadsheet Chart Section-->
        <div class="col-xs-6" background-color steelblue">
            <!--Loadsheet Header-->
            <div class="row" style="background-color:greenyellow;">
                <div class="col-xs-5" style="background-color:navajowhite">5</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color:orange">3</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color:yellow">3 </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1" style="background-color:aqua">1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]